# Is joining a domain on Azure using a virtual network practical on DSL with a slow up link?

Tags: windows-domain, azure, dsl, virtual-network

I'm new to Azure after coming back to the dev/sys admin world after a five year hiatus.  I'm really enjoying it and find it fascinating and powerful.

I was thinking of setting up setting up a domain server on Azure and joining from my home network (currently workgroup based).  There is no practical need to do this, it is simply for learning purposes.

My concern is over the amount of network traffic this will generate over my DSL connection, in particular my slow uplink at 896Kbps, not so much for the downlink a 18Mbs.  When my uplink is saturated it brings all my network internet connections to a crawl.

So my question is whether this is at all practical in this situation?  Or will there be too much background traffic on the uplink to make this practical?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I was thinking of setting up setting up a domain server on Azure and
>   joining from my home network (currently workgroup based).

If you want to deploy your domain server on Azure and join your local PC to it, we should **setup a site-to-site VPN**.

> So my question is whether this is at all practical in this situation?
>   Or will there be too much background traffic on the uplink to make
>   this practical?

Normally, company will create AD DS on local environment, and create another VM on Azure, sync on-prem AD to Azure VM, setup VPN between them, in this way to achieve HA.

In your scenario, we should setup VPN between your local and Azure Vnet, after join the domain, when you login this PC with domain account, it will request to Azure VM, in this time will generate network traffic, but **no too much background traffic**.

Also we can use Azure AD, join your PC(win10) to Azure AD. More information about Azure AD, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/).

Comment: Thanks Jason for the response and the helpful information.  I'm glad to see that it shouldn't generate too much background traffic, so I will give it a try.  As I said there is no practical need to do this (just strictly a learning exercise) so if it causes an issue I will discontinue its use.